# Drupal 9 Webform - Adding Membership to Contribution

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, webform-civicrm

I am trying to build a CiviCRM Webform in Drupal 9.  Everything appears to work well except for the fact that the membership fee for a membership does not add to the total due.

In this screenshot, a lifetime membership is set to $2500. When I click lifetime for the membership (or any of the other paid options) the total does not go up.

[image]

I tried with the *Membership Fee* option selected in the configuration but even when you type in an amount on the form the total does not change.

[image]

If anyone can help guide me to where to configure this correctly I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: pls confirm which version of webform and webform_civicrm you are using. there was a time (perhaps still is) where you need to manually add a webform page break which could be your issue

Comment: I am on Webform module 6.0.3, CiviCRM Webform Integration 8.x-5.0-beta7 and CiviCRM 5.38.0. I looked at the pending patches and none of them looked related.  I will install the dev branch and see if it fixes anything.  Thanks!

Comment: @petednz-fuzion, thank you for the feedback, I installed the dev branch and that did not change the behavior.  You are correct that the total is on the same page.  I have looked around the web and I am not seeing a patch that looks like it is for this.  Thanks!

Comment: have you tried manually adding page break?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion, it does have the page break.  However the total is on the first page and I do not see how to add it tot he second page because it is not a field on the Webform edit page. Thanks!

Comment: if you want to strip your webform down to the minimum (eg Clone, remove extraneous fields), then send to me I will import to a site and take a quick look.

Comment: @petednz that is very kind of you. Here is a Google doc with the config I am testing. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-bKB_U5HOJ_UXL98M96r3R-TL89YpyaunOtwvKeB2hg/edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me once I add the initial 'wizard page' at the top of the Build elements

[image]

so on front end i see

[image]

then

[image]

but I did not enable Membership Fee. do you really need that?

Comment: that works perfectly! Thank you.  I want to use the membership fee because some members may pay an alternative amount.  I will see what I can figure out.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. SE works on basis that you 'accept'the answer, and preferable also +1 it. mostly needed so SE gives the civi channel better ratings for 'questions with an accepted answer

Comment: I am still working on this to look/work how I want it to.  Does the select list for the membership need to be outside of the pages?  I get the default membership name if I put the membership selection inside the first page.  Is this how it should be? Thanks!

Comment: if it is showing default then i think you have the same problem as https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/39884/no-default-with-webform-civicrm-options-field. my fix (which that user says didn't help them) is ... switch that component to static, then disable the option that was showing as default, then save, then reedit, and switch it back to 'live' not 'static'. any help?

Comment: oh lol. that was you too.

Comment: Ugnfotionatly this problem is a little different then that. I will add another question so I can include a screen shot and if you or someone else can help me others can learn from the issue.  Thank you very much for all your help so far!